choice of software to recover files in MSDOS 6.2.2
Please write me your opinion about the software effective for data recovery in MSDOS 6.22. I am interested in the items from the list below and others:

Undelete, developed by Central Point Software

Ontrack Easy recovery

Active@Uneraser

Norton Utility.


The files should be restored from "Sony Index" and "Verbatim Datalifeplus" 2HD floppies. They have FAT file system.

Just to help in the future, you may want to look into the topic of bitrot and how long data is intended to last on floppies.
